# Ethiopic font returned by 'echo' and 'printf' is not visible

Tags: php, html, css, fonts

Edit:
when I use something like

```
   echo 'coming up is ethiopic font: እናመሰግናለን';
```

It works fine
but when there is some ethiopic string returned by function as shown below, the returned string is not visible.

```
      echo 'coming up is ethiopic font:'.my_string();
```

when my_string() returns some ethiopic font, that part will not be visible.

Is there any global setting with PHP? or what can I do ?

As you can see at the footer of the page at [here](http://ethiopianlanguages.com/ethiopian-calendar/) the font is partially visible(it is visible at least if you have the fonts on your pc).

The problem apeared on my host server, but no problem on my local server

EDIT:
My problem seems something different from the php functions. I tried relocating the code from the side bar to the header section, and the same code works fine in the header section, but not in the sidebar. Therefore, I am suspecting something else. I added CSS and HTML tags to the question.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the code of `my_string()`. Most likely it doesn't handle UTF-8 strings...

Comment: But, I am not having problem on my local server.

Comment: Depending on how my_string() gets its data, the problem could be anything. Does the information come from a database? There are all sorts of ways character data can be messed up on the way in or out of the database, and the config could easily be different on your host. Without showing us my_string(), we're reduced to blind guessing.

Comment: I put this  'echo "ትግርኛ ወይም ኦሮሞኛ ሰነዶች እንዲተረጎሙልዎት  ይፈልጋሉ";' in the footer and worked fine. But when I put this same code in the sidebar, it doesn't work. What can you say about this?

Comment: I edited my question. The problem is not with the function return value. I even tried with something like this:  function my_string(){
        return "ኦሮሞኛ ሰነዶች እንዲ";
        }
        echo my_string();
My problem appears when the code is in my sidebar and main section. in the header it works fine.

Comment: The footer, as I see it, contains “የዛሬ ቀን በኢትዮጵያ አቆጣጠር ????, ???? 5, 2005 ትግርኛ ወይም ኦሮሞኛ ሰነዶች እንዲተረጎሙልዎት ይፈልጋሉ”, so it does not work quite fine either. There is something in your PHP code, not visible in the question, that causes the question marks, here as well as in the sidebar.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible problem with encoding. I once had similar issue using Hindi and bengali font. It was solved by playing with `some javascript font library` and `string utf8_encode ( string $data )`. We later replaced it with alternative solution, by embedding css3 web-fonts. CSS3 allows for web-fonts, which is a good solution to such problem.